# Dynamic array name

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can a generate multiple array with this syntax result0, result1, result2 etc..

I tried this and this work :

```
for i in xrange(0, 7):
        var_num = i
        globals()['result%s' % var_num] = []
        globals()['result%s' % var_num].append(1000+i)
        print ['result%s' % var_num][0]
```

it gives me theses array :

```
result0
result1
result2
result3
result4
result5
result6
```

But i'm sure there is another way to do that?...

Thanks

Comment: The right answer is "don't". What's your real use case? Something like a defaultdict of lists might be more appropriate. (Also: Python lists are not arrays -- there *are* libraries offering arrays for Python, but these aren't them -- but that's a separate discussion).

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: It's generally not considered a good practice, in any language that supports it. For some reasons see [_Why you don't want to create dynamic variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [_Never use dynamic variable names_](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/never-use-dynamic-variable-names/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a dictionary.

```
>>> variables = {}
>>> for i in xrange(0, 7):
...     variables['result%s' % i] = [1000 + i]
...
>>> variables
{'result6': [1006], 'result4': [1004], 'result5': [1005], 'result2': [1002], 'result3': [1003], 'result0': [1000], 'result1': [1001]}
>>> variables['result2']
[1002]
>>> variables['result6']
[1006]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have like that? Why not just an array of arrays? You will be able to iterate over the arrays easily when you keep them in another array.